# utility classes in styled component react

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

hi I am using styled componant in react

```
const H4 = styled.h4`
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 0.38px;
  line-height: 1.33;
  color: red;
  padding: 20px;
`;

<H4>Small header</H4>
```

it will give exsact style in H4 tag. but how can I override this padding with utility classes like `m-b-10` it will give `margin-bottom:10px`

something like this `<H4 m-b-10>small header</H4>`

same time I need to use this utility class whereever I want. in css I can simply write

```
m-b-10{margin-bottom:10px !important};
```

how can achieve this things on styled componenet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the best solutions is to use https://styled-system.com/, it plays well with **Styled Components** and other libraries like **Emotion** and it offers what you need, to use utility-classes in the component definition.

Example:

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { color, space, fontSize } from 'styled-system'

// Set default styles and add styled-system functions to your component
const Box = styled.div`

  /*defaut styles */
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 20px;

  /* configurable properties */;
  ${color};
  ${space};
  ${fontSize};

`;
```

And to use it:

```
  <Box bg="black" >
    Lorem Ipsum
  </Box>  

  <Box bg="black" color="green" fontSize="12px" p="10px">
    Lorem Ipsum
  </Box>
```

That code, will render this:
[image: styled-components with utility functions]

It also supports Media-Querys, Themes etc..

You can play with this **CodeAndSandbox** where it is been used with **Styled Components** https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-with-styled-system-njr17

Answer (score 2):

You can define utility classes in the top component of your React tree. The example uses Gatsby.js, but you can easily adapt it for other React framework.

```
// src/components/layout.js
const GlobalStyles = createGlobalStyles`
  html {
    /* Put your CSS variables here*/
  }
  .m-b-10 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
`
```

Then make whatever defined in `createGlobalStyles` available for access in child components.

```
// src/components/layout.js
export default function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <GlobalStyle />
      {children}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

```
// src/pages.index.js
import Layout from "../components/layout"
const H4 = styled.h4`
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 0.38px;
  line-height: 1.33;
  color: red;
  padding: 20px;
`;
const IndexPage = () => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <H4 className="m-b-10" />
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use variables like

```
const m-b-10 = '20px';
const H4 = styled.h4`
   padding: ${m-b-10};
`;
```

You can define such variables in a separate file and import them to styles components

Comment: good. can I get this value on directly jsx. like <H4 space-btn></H4>

Comment: bcz dont like to chage h4 style I seaking some edge case here. this place only my H4 is diffrent

Comment: What if you just add `class="space-btn"` on the jsx where you use styled component? I think it'll keep it

Comment: just now I did. I dont know whether it is best practice or not